# Why does Area 51 display "today" on right?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

On Meta (and, I think, all other sites), user specific info is shown left to right chronologically, with "today" on left:

[image]

However, the new Area 51 shows today on the right:

[image]

Why is this? This is only with the new Area 51 format (was not on old format). I would prefer them all to be the same (consistent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. This was inadvertently caused by changes to Area 51 CSS, when `.subtabs a` went from `float: right` to `float: left`.